# How can i compare/diff directories using Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I need to be able to compare a folder in one location with the same folder in another. Is there a way to do this with mercurial?

I've tried

`hg diff path1 path2` and a couple of variants of this with no success.

Our current workaround is to use an external tool to manually compare on our local computers.

Thanks,

Comment: On Windows i usually use WinMerge to do this, it has good directory comparison features. I also use it as the diff tool that hg will spawn.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you still don't use TortoiseHG, it's a good reason to install and use it - with a set of mergetools (some of which have `dirdiff=True`) comparing of trees will be just a question of selecting two folders and comparing (using needed tool from pre-filled list)
2. Even in pure console you can enable [extdiff extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) and

   - with minimal delay use the -p option to specify an external diff utility for comparing files `hg extdiff -p YOURTOOL dir1 dir2`
   - **or** [configure extdiff](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension#Create_Custom_extdiff_Commands), add your differ as special new command (with optional custom parameters) and run it as `hg YOURTOOL dir1 dir2`